# Check if a specific page was seen in previous step - if so, trigger a virtual pageview tag

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I need to start tracking virtual pageviews for a specific goal-completion. There is one condition though - user needs to see a specific page prior to sending the virtual pageview. I have to stick to pure GTM solution - any tips how to check if a specific page was seen in previous step? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest (but not most reliable) way would be to create a javascript macro that reads out document.referer.  Then create a rule "if referrer equals mypage.html" and use it to fire tags. This does not work well for pages with frames, some browsers do not send a referrer etc. but should be "good enough".

If you need more precision nothing stops you from setting cookie via GTM (with a custom script tag) and store the previous page there.